# React Native Picker moves back to first item after scrolling and do not select correct value

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm working with Picker component from React Native and I'm having some issues.

I'm trying to make a product registration page where each product has a catalog, so I'm using a Picker to show all catalogs that have been registered in the application. But, when I scroll the picker, it moves back to first item and when I press the button to registrate a product, I have the catalog field with undefined value. I'm using Formik for it.

**Picker component**:

```
              <Picker
                style={{ height: 10, width: 325 }}
                value={this.state.selectedValue}
                mode="dropdown"
                itemStyle={{
                  backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
                  color: 'black',
                  height: 120,
                  marginTop: 25,
                  fontFamily: 'Ebrima',
                  fontSize: 17,
                  borderRadius: 5,
                  borderColor: '#7e2f89',
                }}             
                onValueChange={this.optionChanged}>
                {this.state.catalogs.map((member, key) => {
                  return (
                    <Picker.Item
                      label={member.name}
                      value={member.name}
                      key={key}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </Picker>
```

**State** and **optionChanged**:

```
 state = {
    catalogs: [],
    selectedValue: '',
  };

  optionChanged = value => {
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value});
  };
```

Formik with initial values:

```
  <Formik
        initialValues={{
          name: '',
          description: '',
          costPrice: '',
          salePrice: '',
          catalog: '',
          amountStock: '',
        }} ...
```

How can I make it work properly?